# Trying to store every value of array for each 6 interactions

Tags: python, arrays, list, data-structures

im iterating over a list with x elements, and for each 6 elements, im storing these elements into another variable (list1, list2, list3), but the biggest problem on my workaround is that my code its excluding the rest of elements if its not going to be exactly 6 elements, let me show an example:

Lets suppose i've an array starting from 1 to 20, when saving elements into lists variable as i previously mentioned, it will stop on list3 saving just (13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18), so the value of lists would be like:

list1: (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)
list2: (7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12)
list3: (13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18)

but the correctly value should be

list1: (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 19, 20)
list2: (7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12)
list3: (13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18)

Im gonna let the code i did here below.

***Code:***

```
array = list(range(1, 100))

result = list(zip(* [iter(array)] * 6))

for item in result:
   print(item)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```py
array = range(1, 100)

result = [[], [], []]

for i, x in enumerate(array):
    result[int(i / 6) % 3].append(x)

print(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

My solution isn't particularly pythonic, but it accomplishes what you are trying to achieve:

the code:

```
foo = list(range(1, 100))
lists = []
temp = []
for i in foo:
    temp.append(i)
    if len(temp) == 6:
        lists.append(temp)
        temp = []
if len(temp) > 0:
    lists[0] += temp

for list in lists:
    print(list)
```

has an output of:

> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 97, 98, 99]

> [7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]

> [13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18]

> [19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24]

> [25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30]

> [31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36]

> [43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48]

> [49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54]

> [55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60]

> [61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66]

> [67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72]

> [73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78]

> [79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84]

> [85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90]

> [91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96]

Comment: Yeah, its kind C like, but its so easy to understand, thanks alot, it helped me so much!!

Comment: That's always my goal! Glad I could help.